# VB.Net Word Tables: Select specific Cells in Column

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop, vb.net-2010

I wrote a program that creates a table in Word which is filled with values from a database. That works fine so far.
The first column of that table shall contain categories for items in the table and those categories should be merged cells with the span of all items in that category. Basically this is working.

Here's the code

```
'Select the first cell of a category in column 1
wordtable.Cell(categoryPos, 1).Select() 
'Move down till all cells of column 1 in rows with items of that category are selected
word.Selection.MoveDown(wordoptions.WdUnits.wdLine, (numberMachines - 1), wordoptions.WdMovementType.wdExtend)
'then I change the rotation, background-color, write text etc.
```

The problem is the page break. After a page break the listing looks like on this picture:

[image: Wrong Selection]

I need to know a method of selecting multiple cells without the Move-command.
If this was Excel I would do something like

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(x1, y1), Cells(x2, y2)).Select
Selection.Merge()
```

But since Words range is only one-dimensional I'm kinda stuck here.

Someone got a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's easier than expected:

```
Dim r As wordoptions.Range
r = doc.Range( _
Start:=wordtable.Cell(kategorypos, 1).Range.Start, _
End:=wordtable.Cell((kategorypos + numberMachines - 1), 1).Range.End)
r.Select()
```